# ADTr20 doesnt get installed in my eclipse

Tags: android

I have updated my android sdk to sdkr20, before i used r16 and my eclipse version is

Version: Indigo Service Release 1
Build id: 20110916-0149

but when I try to install ADTr20 it doesnt get installed and says

```
Cannot complete the install because one or more required items could not be found.
  Software being installed: Android Native Development Tools 20.0.0.v201206242043-391819 (com.android.ide.eclipse.ndk.feature.group 20.0.0.v201206242043-391819)
```

What should I do now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest trying a fresh install of eclipse.  But don't get Juno (the latest version) as there is a bug that makes the XML editors not work with ADT (see http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=34630).

Answer (score 0):

Can you try updating eclipse first?

[image]

Then let it do its thing like so:

[image]

Then select the option only for tools (do not select anything else)

[image]

Once that installs successfully, try installing the other updates one by one, say select DDMS only first and so on

**Note:** At times, removing development tools and then installing it again helps to resolve such issues as well

Answer (score 0):

They say you should use Eclipse Indigo